# gstreamer plugin: how to implementation a httpserver source

Tags: c, gstreamer

Recently, I'm extending the capability of gstreamer, which is a popular multimedia video/audio processing framework.

In fact, I want to develop a gstreamer plugin, which is a httpserver based source element. So I inherit the GstPushSrc code, and add some libevent server function in the create function. Thus, a http client could post some image/video/audio data to my server source, the downstream elements will receive the data from gbuffer.

However, I find I cannot let the server wait for new data, and it crashed soon after I start the pipeline, because the behind sink needs data right now, so the bus throw a failure. I don't know how to make such a source element to wait or ingested for new data. Could anyone help me? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like your pipeline may not be in the correct scheduling mode. Can you please post your code that you use to set up the pipeline?